# PostgreSQL Auto Partitioning, StatementInvalid: PG::NullValueNotAllowed

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to import a huge address database from a set of CSV files. I following a [tutorial](https://medium.com/@StreamBright/creating-partitions-automatically-in-postgresql-7006d68c0fbb) to create postgres partitions automatically.

I create my database with eighteen fields. Every field is a varchar. The field I want to use for partitioning is "comune".

Following the guide I create this function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION create_partition_and_insert() RETURNS trigger AS
  $BODY$
    DECLARE
      partition_comune TEXT;
      partition TEXT;
    BEGIN
      partition := TG_RELNAME || '_' || partition_comune;
      IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT relname FROM pg_class WHERE relname=partition) THEN
        RAISE NOTICE 'A partition has been created %',partition;
        EXECUTE 'CREATE TABLE ' || partition || ' (check (comune = ''' || NEW.comune || ''')) INHERITS (' || TG_RELNAME || ');';
      END IF;
      EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO ' || partition || ' SELECT(' || TG_RELNAME || ' ' || quote_literal(NEW) || ').* RETURNING patent_id;';
      RETURN NULL;
    END;
  $BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
COST 100;
```

And then

```
CREATE TRIGGER address_list_insert_trigger
BEFORE INSERT ON address_list
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE create_partition_and_insert();
```

When I try to insert a record (I use activerecord orm but with psql is the same) I have en error:

```
PG::NullValueNotAllowed: ERROR:  query string argument of EXECUTE is null
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function create_partition_and_insert() line 9 at EXECUTE
: INSERT INTO "address_list" ("id_egon", "regione", "provincia", "comune", "frazione", "procom_2016", "ist_sez", "ist_pro", "ist_com", "dug", "via", "presso", "colore", "num_civ", "esponente", "civ_extraurb", "liv_serv100_30", "linea_lunga") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11, $12, $13, $14, $15, $16, $17, $18)
```

Where is my fault?

Comment: How many rows do you expect that you think you need partitioning before even doing performance testing?

Comment: Basically this is an address book db with about 15 million records. I just need a query: I have to query for "comune" and then I manipulate the results with Vue.js.
Some "comune" has 50 records, some "comune" has 500.000 records

Comment: You won't need partitioning for only 15 million rows. Proper [indexing](http://use-the-index-luke.com/) will probably be enough